# How to link ruby.h to C++ CMake project

Tags: c++, ruby, cmake, linker

I'm currently trying to build a project in Windows (I'm not using Linux to develop it because my final target is my app to be fully usable in Windows) with C++ & CMake that needs to call some ruby functions. I'd like to use the Ruby C API (http://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/c/), that needs to `#include "ruby.h"`, but I can't manage to link it propperly to my code. I don't know if there is a better alternative than this API.

I tried to use `find_package(Ruby REQUIRED)`, but doesn't work, throwing:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
[cmake]   Could NOT find Ruby (missing: Ruby_INCLUDE_DIR Ruby_LIBRARY
[cmake]   Ruby_CONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR) (found suitable version "3.1.3", minimum required
[cmake]   is "1.8.0")
```

It is detecting my version of Ruby 3.1.3, but won't use it and just throw an exception saying that it couldn't find Ruby. 
I tried to build ruby from the GitHub repository and then link the .o generated files with my project, but that dind't look like a good idea (and it didn't work, as expected).

Also, I'm new to this kind of C++ projects with difficult compiling/linking (and CMake itself), so sorry if this is a noob question.

Comment: Cmake is saying Ruby application is installed, but Ruby development files are not installed. How did you install ruby?

Comment: I used RubyInstaller (https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

Comment: Why don't you install it as usual for msys2 like `pacman -S ruby`?

Comment: Have you called `ridk enable` in cmd or PowerShell as it's required on rubyinstaller.org?

Comment: I got it to work, but now it throws the error 
`fatal error: sys/select.h: No such file or directory`.
After some researching I found that this header is linux only, but it is inside my 
`msys2/usr/include/sys` (not in msys2/mingw64/include), and it can't find it. Is there some package to include it?

Comment: Look in MinGW installer for a package containing "pthread" in its name and install missing packages.

Comment: I found `mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git` (https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git?repo=mingw64) and I've installed it, but apparently nothing changes

Comment: Looks good, IDK what else is required.

Comment: Looking in the files section of the link, this does not include nothing related to the file I'm missing, so I don't know what this does

Answer (score 0):

You're terminology is a bit off. Header files are just a C/C++ code, which you can include, but you can't link them. There are two flavours of `#include`,

```
#include "ruby.h"
```

Will first search for "ruby.h" in the same directory as the file that does this include, and if the file wasn't found it will search the *include* paths. You can specify the path to the file instead; and

```
#include <ruby.h>
```

Will search for `ruby.h` *only* in the include directories, which can be specified in CMakeFile or in %INCLUDE% environment variable.

I would recommend you to find the path to `ruby.h` and modify your CMakeFile like this:

```
include_directories(
  path/to/folder
  # ...others...
)
```

Comment: Almost whole answer is incorrect. The both #include search in include directories. The second one doesn't search in a current file directory. The therm "current directory" is used incorrectly. Finding the path and using it in `include_directories` is a bad advise.

Comment: @273K I have corrected my answer. Can you clarify why adding a path to `include_directories` is a bad advice and what's the better way to do it?

Comment: I've done that, (I know this isn't the best way to do this, but I'm just testing)
`target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PUBLIC "${SOURCE_DIR}${HEADER}/ruby-3.1.0"
    PUBLIC "${SOURCE_DIR}${HEADER}/ruby-3.1.0/x64-mingw-ucrt"
)`
but I still need to link the ruby library, as said in the guide I linked before
"Embedding Ruby requires one header ruby.h, which includes a platform-specific header ruby/config.h. You will probably need to tell your compiler about the include paths for these headers. You will also need to link with the Ruby lib."

Comment: @FuegoFatuo25 that seems like more of a cmake question than a Ruby question. Your Ruby installation should have included the compiled library (possibly a dll?). I'm not familiar with cmake, but there must be a way to specify that you want it to link with that library.